# Port forwarding works on Ubuntu but doesn't work on windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows, port-forwarding

I set up my wireless router to port forward 80 -> 80 (as well as 8080 -> 80) to my local http server. I have dual boot windows + ubuntu and both of them have apache installed. The problem is if I boot ubuntu the port forwarding is working fine but if I boot windows (still same IP) port forwarding doesn't work.

I've disabled firewall but it doesn't help. I tried accessing it through the proxy - still no luck. Could you tell what could be the problem on windows machine? I suspect if router config is working for Ubuntu then I shouldn't bother to change anything on the router side, isn't it?

The event logs (when in windows) is showing this warning (yellow triangle with exclamation mark):

```
Warning     Jul 29 22:50:57 FIREWALL rule : Protocol: TCP Src ip: 188.220.xx.xx Src port: 51522 Dst ip: 192.168.1.66 Dst port: 80 Chain: forward_host_service Rule Id: 1 Action: accept

Warning     Jul 29 22:50:56 FIREWALL rule : Protocol: TCP Src ip: 188.220.xx.xx Src port: 51521 Dst ip: 192.168.1.66 Dst port: 80 Chain: forward_host_service Rule Id: 1 Action: accept

Warning     Jul 29 22:50:56 FIREWALL rule : Protocol: TCP Src ip: 188.220.xx.xx Src port: 51520 Dst ip: 192.168.1.66 Dst port: 80 Chain: forward_host_service Rule Id: 1 Action: accept
```

P.S. 188.220.xx.xx is my external IP (shown by 'my ip' pages) and I can't ping to it

**EDIT:** And I can ping external IP from Ubuntu (but not from windows) there is the log from router when accessed from Ubuntu(still warning but works):

```
Warning     Jul 30 08:46:52 FIREWALL rule : Protocol: TCP Src ip: 188.220.xx.xx Src port: 32897 Dst ip: 192.168.1.66 Dst port: 80 Chain: forward_host_service Rule Id: 1 Action: accept

Warning     Jul 30 08:46:52 FIREWALL rule : Protocol: TCP Src ip: 188.220.xx.xx Src port: 32896 Dst ip: 192.168.1.66 Dst port: 80 Chain: forward_host_service Rule Id: 1 Action: accept
```

Comment: Are you sure your firewall is off?  Going by the events shown it would indicate it's still on.  Maybe you've got the firewall set for the wrong network type, public, work, or home?

Comment: are you sure apache on windows is answering on port 80?

Comment: I'm sure it is answering to port 80 locally both with localhost & 192.168.1.66. In regards to firewall I checked 'Turn off' for both local and public networks in control panel -> firewall. There is a firewall section on router configuration but it works on Ubuntu. And this 'Rule id 1' I think means that 1'st port forwarding rule (80->80) is in action (second is 8080 ->80)

Comment: Can it be that I need to modify smth on router to make it work for windows? For me it looks very unlikely